# Is there a way to generate a spline centered within a font?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, fonts

I would like to do something that seems simple, but I can't find anything on the web.  Does anyone know of a way to take a font and generate a spline that follows the center of the font's stroke?  I have the Adobe creative suite.